# Simple js loop using null as a condition

Tags: javascript, loops

/i am trying to make a simple loop. i can't seem to get it to work.

```
var c =0;
while (x !== false) {
x = men[c].plat;
if (x == "null") {break;}
f =  f + x + "<br>";
c++;
}   


var men = [
{"plat": 7},
{"plat": 1},
{"plat": null }];
```

I just want the loop to see the "null" string and then leave the loop. 
thanks

Comment: `null` and `"null"` are not the same thing.

Comment: `null` is not a string.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to check for string, check for `x === null`, and you could use for loop, like:

```
    var men = [
        {"plat": 7},
        {"plat": 1},
        {"plat": null }];

    for(var i = 0, len = men.length; i < len; i++) {
        var obj = men[i];
        if( obj.plat === null ) {
            //null data encountered
        }
    }
```

See for [null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming everything else is fine, your check should be `x === null` since `null` is a keyword, not a string. Also, your declaration of `men` needs to be before the loop, or else that's not accessible.

Tip: Do yourself a huge favor and pick more descriptive variable names. A good rule of thumb is to never use 1-character variable names that aren't loop counters.